# How do you add text after displaying the post date for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently, I have the following code that hooks when the date is displayed. I want this to code to effect dates on listed posts (index.php) and a single post.

```
function rating_after_date()
{
return printf(
     'Ratings: %s'
    ,get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_rating', true )
);

}
add_action( 'get_the_date', 'rating_after_date' );
```

It changes the date but not the way I want it to:

```
Ratings: 0Ratings: 010
```

I would like the posts to the display the date like:

```
March 22, 2016 | Rating: <somenumber>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That filter takes in parameter the date, date format and post id.
You could do something like this :

```
function rating_after_date($date, $d, $post_id)
{
    return $date . printf(' | Ratings: %s'
                 ,get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_rating', true )
);

add_action( 'get_the_date', 'rating_after_date' );
```

Mote that you should adjust the priority of your new filter so that it executes at the end of the stack.

Here is a good example : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_date